# How to Update a User's Name and how it Appears in SharePoint 2013 Front End

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, user-accounts

I have a handful of users that were entered in AD incorrectly (instead of their full name, they were entered by their username). I have made the corrections in AD, forced a Full Sync, and names are now all pulling correctly in the USPA service.

Upon the initial entry of the name in a list, the full name is pulling correctly, but once it has been submitted, it is switching the name back to their username. I have also noticed that information is correct in the user's My Site, but in the upper-right drop-down, it is still appearing as their username.

Please help!

Comment: some timetime full import not fix it...as a recomended approach is Full sync followed by couple of incremental sync

Comment: Hi Waqas, I followed your steps and this was still unsuccessful. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: how many users are facing the issue

Comment: Currently about 10, though I see potential for more. It really just depends on when I run across the ones that were entered incorrectly in AD.